# PWA - How to check for updates?

Tags: javascript, node.js, progressive-web-apps, workbox

I have a progressive web app which works as intended.

But now I want to know how to check if the site has changed (if the user is online) so the user gets the newest version.

Right now I need to hard reload or wait till the service worker does this automatically.

I've checked many sites including

https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules/workbox-build#full_generatesw_config

but could not find an answer.

#### How can I archive that? E.g using `navigator.serviceWorker`.

Comment: Maybe this part of the documentation will help? https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules/workbox-broadcast-cache-update Otherwise, this question is awfully broad.

Comment: @HereticMonkey thanks! I check that.